# jquery swap div to new div on click

Tags: jquery

I am wanting to have 2 divs , and when you click on a specific element in a div , have that entire div moved to a new div , and then back again if clicked.

I have something sort of working , but it just moved the specific a class and not the entire div that is wrapping it.

http://jsfiddle.net/uw446/249/

```
<div class="lineup-table">
       <div  id="choose-players" class="player-left">
         <div id="lineup" class="player-row"><a>Players Name 1</a><a class="swap">SWAP 1</a></div>
         <div id="lineup" class="player-row"><a>Players Name 2</a><a class="swap">SWAP 2</a></div>
       </div>
       <div  id="selected-players" class="player-right">
         <div id="lineup" class="player-row-selected"><a>Players Name 1</a><a class="swap">SWAP 3</a></div>
         <div id="lineup" class="player-row-selected"><a>Players Name 2</a><a class="swap">SWAP 4</a></div>
       </div>
</div>
```

here is what i have so far for the function , but again not working properly

```
$(".swap").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this);        
     if($(this).closest("#lineup").length>0){
        $this.removeClass("player-row").addClass("player-row-selected").prependTo("#selected-players");
    } else {
        $this.removeClass("player-row-selected").addClass("player-row").prependTo("#choose-players");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the IDs: they must be unique. So instead to have multiple id="lineup" you may add lineup as an additional class and use as ids lineup followed by a number.

Moreover you need to check if the current element is under the player-left or not in order to decide the operation to do:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".swap").on("click", function() {
    var $thisDiv = $(this).closest(".lineup");
    if($thisDiv.closest(".player-left").length>0){
      $(this).removeClass("player-row").addClass("player-row-selected");
      $thisDiv.closest(".lineup").prependTo("#selected-players")
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("player-row-selected").addClass("player-row");
      $thisDiv.closest(".lineup").prependTo("#choose-players");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.lineup-table { width:400px }
.player-left,.player-right { width:196px; display: inline-block;border: 1px solid red; vertical-align:top }
.player-row-selected, .player-row{ height:50px; background-color:#ccc; cursor:pointer;border:1px solid black;margin:5px}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div class="lineup-table">
    <div  id="choose-players" class="player-left">
        <div id="lineup1" class="lineup player-row"><a>Players Name 1</a><a class="swap">SWAP 1</a></div>
        <div id="lineup2" class="lineup player-row"><a>Players Name 2</a><a class="swap">SWAP 2</a></div>
    </div>
    <div  id="selected-players" class="player-right">
        <div id="lineup3" class="lineup player-row-selected"><a>Players Name 3</a><a class="swap">SWAP 3</a></div>
        <div id="lineup4" class="lineup player-row-selected"><a>Players Name 4</a><a class="swap">SWAP 4</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting the containing div

```
$('#lineup').on('click', '.swap', function
```

This way the target never changes position after the document loads.